# How to send structured data to a REST endpoint that retrieves objects? Which HTTP verb should be used?

Tags: json, rest, http, restful-architecture, http-verbs

I want to construct a REST endpoint to **retrieve** objects, but I need to send structured data as query parameters (e.g. a list). I was wondering if those data could be sent as request body (see example below). How should I handle this in order to stick to REST good practices? Which HTTP verb should I use?

URI:

```
http://localhost:8080/products
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "name" : "Computer",
    "categories" : [
        { 
            "id" : 1

        },
        { 
            "id" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Computer XP 2040",
        "price": 800
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "HP Computer",
        "price": 2000
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Smart Computer",
        "price": 1200
    }
]
```

Comment: POST would be the normal one

Comment: I'm concerned about POST because my search is idempotent and also I'm not creating a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST` is not correct for this. If you want to stick to RESTful best practices, you must encode the information in the uri.

Note that `POST` might be better if you don't want to do this, but since this question was about REST best practices (and not http services in general), `POST` is your go-to.

I would simply encode this as:

```
 GET /products?name=Computer&categories=1,4
```

Comment: Can you provide a source for "If you want to stick to RESTful best practices, you must encode the information in the uri."?

Comment: @EricStein literally any introduction to REST will tell you this Eric. GET = for retrieving information.

Comment: @EricStein here's one extremely reputable one: https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Comment: Indeed. As I'm retrieving data as an idempotent operation, POST should not be used. Nice discussion guys, thanks. I've edited the question in order to make it more reasonable. If you guys think it's a reasonable one, please consider voting. Regards.